# Setting ALLUSERS in WiX for per-user or per-machine installation context

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I use WiX 3.5. My installer should enable both per-user and per-machine installation. I would like to achieve that by using radio buttons ("Everyone" and "Just me").

I found a couple of references on the Internet:

- Selecting current-user or all-users install: *[Adding a user interface](http://www.merlinia.com/mdt/WiXTutorial2.msl)*, part of *Yet Another WiX Tutorial - Part 2 - Adding the UI*.
- Set the ALLUSERS property to an empty string: *[Using WiX 3.0 to create a per-user MSI that does not prompt for elevation on Windows Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/11/18/6385121.aspx)*

If I understand that correctly my installer should set ALLUSERS property to 1 for per-machine installation and to "" (empty string) for per-user installation.

My problem is no matter what I try ALLUSERS is always set to 1. Even when I don't set it at all!

Here is a couple of things I tried:

```
<Control Id="UserSelection"
         Type="RadioButtonGroup"
         X="26"
         Y="115"
         Width="305"
         Height="45"
         Property="ASSISTANCE_USERS"
         Text="ASSISTANCE_USERS">
    <RadioButtonGroup Property="ASSISTANCE_USERS">
        <RadioButton Value="cur"
                     X="0"
                     Y="0"
                     Width="295"
                     Height="16"
                     Text="Just me" />
        <RadioButton Value="all"
                     X="0"
                     Y="20"
                     Width="295"
                     Height="16"
                     Text="Everyone" />
    </RadioButtonGroup>
</Control>
```

and then setting the ALLUSERS based on ASSISTANCE_USERS:

```
  <Publish Property="ALLUSERS"
           Value="{}">ASSISTANCE_USERS = "cur"</Publish> <!-- set null value -->
  <Publish Property="ALLUSERS"
           Value="1">ASSISTANCE_USERS = "all"</Publish>
```

However, ALLUSERS is always 1.

I also tried just setting ALLUSERS to an empty string:

```
<Property Id="ALLUSERS" Secure="yes"/>
```

This should set ALLUSERS to "", yet it stays "1"

Once I'm able to set ALLUSERS, I should be able to use HKMU for per-user and per-machine installtion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check a verbose log (using /l*vx): MSI logs every property change so you can see when ALLUSERS is being set.

Comment: Hi Bob, that's exactly what I did. There is only one line in the log: Property(C): ALLUSERS = 1

Comment: Then ALLUSERS is set in your .msi's Property table. Are you using Package/@InstallScope?

Comment: I just check out you [blog](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/04/01/new-wix-feature-setting-package-installation-scope/). I didn't use Package/@InstallScope. When I try InstallScope="perUser" I still get ALLUSER=1. Documentation says that setting InstallScope="perMachine" sets ALLUSER to 1. Should InstallScope="perUser" set ALLUSER to ""? What else could set ALLUSERS to 1?

Comment: Nothing else in WiX sets ALLUSERS. If you're using any third party libraries or merge modules, they're a likely source.

Comment: Thanks @Bob! Yes, I use merge module to include VC Redistributables.       `<Merge Id='VS80_CRT' SourceFile='c:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules\microsoft_vc80_crt_x86.msm' Language='0'DiskId='1' />`. This merge module sets ALLUSERS to 1. I also succeeded to change ALLUSERS to "" by using the approach from [http://www.merlinia.com/mdt/WiXTutorial2.msl]