# Upgrade Minimal Installer to Per User \ Per Machine Installer

Tags: c#, wix, installation

I've created a minimal installer for my `DLL` using `WIX`.

How can I upgrade it so that it contains a dialog which asks the user if to install per user or per machine?

Comment: For a 'dll', what's the difference?

Comment: @ChrisBint, If the program registry entries are defined for Current_User or on Local_Machine. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411585/setting-allusers-in-wix-for-per-user-or-per-machine-installation-context might get you where you want to go